# Sort DataTable by week and day

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I use jQuery [datatables](/questions/tagged/datatables) to build up the table that shows project progress in the following format:

```
Project   |Stage   |Start   |Finish
____________________________________
project 1 |stage 1 |W1D1    |W2D2
project 1 |stage 2 |W2D3    |W4D5
...
```

Project milestones are measured in the form 'W_D_' (Week, Day).
The problem is when I start sorting by column `Start` or `Finish` it doesn't work properly.

My code so far:

**HTML**:

```
<table id="projectStatus">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Project</th><th>Stage</th><th>Start</th><th>Finish</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>project 1</td><td>stage 1</td><td>W1D1</td><td>W2D2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>project 1</td><td>stage 2</td><td>W2D3</td><td>W11D5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>project 1</td><td>stage 3</td><td>W11D6</td><td>W5D6</td>
        </tr>       
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JS**:

```
$('#projectStatus').DataTable({
    orderable: true,
  processing: true,
  defaultContent: '',
  pageLength: 10
});
```

How do I fix that sorting issue? Thank you.

Comment: Hi, what sorting issue? how doesn't it work?

Comment: When I sort above data by `Start` column in ascending order it places `W11D6` **before** `W1D1`. That's, basically, the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your data has numeric nature, I'm afraid, you can't benefit from `data-order`/`data-sort` attributes of corresponding table cells which will sort your rows *alphabetically*.

The way out (without loading extra plug-in) is to set up your own custom data type (say 'weekday') and corresponding sorting method for that:

```js
//init DataTable
$('#projectStatus').DataTable({
//set data type 'weekday' for columns 2, 3
  columnDefs: [{
    targets: [2,3],
    type: 'weekday'
  }]
});
//turn 'week+day' string into number of days
const weekDay2Num = str => ([week, day] = str.match(/W(\d+)D(\d+)/).slice(1), week*7+day);
//specify sorting method for type 'weekday'
Object.assign($.fn.DataTable.ext.oSort, {
  'weekday-asc': (a,b) => weekDay2Num(a)-weekDay2Num(b),
  'weekday-desc': (a,b) => weekDay2Num(b)-weekDay2Num(a)
});
```

```html
<script type="application/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<table id="projectStatus">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Project</th><th>Stage</th><th>Start</th><th>Finish</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>project 1</td><td>stage 1</td><td>W1D1</td><td>W2D2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>project 1</td><td>stage 2</td><td>W2D3</td><td>W11D5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>project 1</td><td>stage 3</td><td>W11D6</td><td>W5D6</td>
        </tr>       
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `data-order` attribute to the cells. DataTables will use this value to order your rows instead of the text inside. You can concatenate the `Week` and `Day` in this attribute.

```html
<table id="projectStatus">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Project</th><th>Stage</th><th>Start</th><th>Finish</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>project 1</td><td>stage 1</td><td data-order="11">W1D1</td><td data-order="22">W2D2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>project 1</td><td>stage 2</td><td data-order="23">W2D3</td><td data-order="115">W11D5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>project 1</td><td>stage 3</td><td data-order="116">W11D6</td><td data-order="56">W5D6</td>
        </tr>       
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should provide the wrong results.

What I see is that you have string values, which are not treated as numbers. E.g., `W11D5` is shown before `W2D3`.

Try to use the `data-order` attribute, concatenating week and day:

```
<td>project 1</td>
<td>stage 2</td>
<td data-order="23">W2D3</td>
<td data-order="115">W11D5</td>
```

If it still doesn't work, zero-pad it:

```
<td>project 1</td>
<td>stage 2</td>
<td data-order="023">W2D3</td>
<td data-order="115">W11D5</td>
```